# Is Telegram username unique?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

When I work over bot development, I found that messages that comes from user have some field called `username`, e. g.

```
{
    update_id: 123567890,
    message: {
        message_id: 1,
        from: {
            id: 1234567890,
            is_bot: false,
            first_name: "Kappa",
            last_name: "Pride",
            username: "kappapride",
        }
    ...
}
```

Does this field contains an unique value, such as `id` field? I know, I can make a TG link with it (like `@kappapride`), but I'm not sure if this field presents for each TG user.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only one user can have `@kappapride` (I believe channels and groups can also take it) username at the same time but users can change their username at any time so **no**, it's definitely not fine to consider it as unique identifier for users.

Comment: Thank you, you have completely answered my question!